# How to use Vuex in Vue using vue-enterprise-boilerplate

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I am trying to use Vuex in chrisvfritz/vue-enterprise-boilerplate.
But I am unsure on how to proceed.

My `<script>` part of a "courses.vue" view component looks like this:

```
<script>
import Layout from '@layouts/main'
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  page: {
    title: 'Courses',
    meta: [{ name: 'description', content: 'Courses' }],
  },
  components: { Layout },
  mounted: () => {
    this.setTitle('courses')
    this.setIcon('about balance')
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['setTitle', 'setIcon']),
  },
}
</script>
```

Other answers on how to use Vuex tell me to use:

```
import store from '@state/store'

new Vue({
    store
});
```

But the "courses.vue" view component does not a a "new Vue" part.

The error I am getting is: "_this.setTitle is not a function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation:

```
new Vue({
    store
});
```

Is actually:

```
new Vue({
    store: store
});
```

So, to get the same outcome, just add a `store: store` to your `export default {` object.

Though, I must say, you probably want to add that `store` to the main `Vue` object, not a component's. *Note:* From what I see (https://github.com/chrisvfritz/vue-enterprise-boilerplate/blob/master/src/main.js) the code already adds the `store`, sou you wouldn't have to.

> The error I am getting is: "_this.setTitle is not a function".

The error comes from here:

```
  mounted: () => {
    this.setTitle('courses')
    this.setIcon('about balance')
  },
```

In this notation, inside the `mounted` function the `this` won't refer to the `Vue` instance, but to other object (possibly `window`). Here's the notation I suggest:

```
  mounted() {
    this.setTitle('courses')
    this.setIcon('about balance')
  },
```

Other than that, you could do `mounted: function() {`, but I think that the notation above is cleaner (the only reason I wouldn't use it is browser support, but since you were using `()=>{}`, I'm assuming you are targeting newer browsers).